# Is "prune down" correct usage?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, word-usage, email, redundancy

Prune meaning to cut down something or chop down.
I am writing to a user that I am removing additional permissions from her profile which are irrelevant to her daily work. So would it be correct if I say, "I am pruning down on your permissions"?

In my opinion, using "down" after "prune" would be redundancy.

Comment: *Prune* doesn't mean to chop down something, it means to cut it back. (A possible exception is those perennial plants which you can chop to the ground each year, and which still grow back the next year.)

Comment: I would just use _pruning_ rather than _pruning down on_.

Comment: The word that really doesn't belong in that sentence is *on*. You can say *pruning your roses down* and *pruning your roses*, and they have slightly different meanings (*down* meaning the rose bushes won't be as tall when you're done). But *pruning on your roses* and *pruning down on your roses* aren't good English.

Comment: *Down* is redundant, but pruning has the same quality as *rightsizing*, when it's your job that is being eliminated: an unwelcome euphemism. You can honestly say you are removing, reducing, or closing irrelevant permissions.

Comment: [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prune+the%2Cprune+down+the%2Cprune+your%2Cprune+down+your&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprune%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprune%20down%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprune%20your%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprune%20down%20your%3B%2Cc0) indicate that 'prune down the/your ...' are not unknown, but are very rare compared with 'prune the/your ...'. While 'protest the finding' and 'protest against the finding' are both fine, I'd avoid 'prune down on ...'. 'Prune' or 'cut down on' (!)